# The meaning of "Itai" in this sentence

Tags: vocabulary

It seems to refer to a place. But which?

> I thought it was Greek, maybe,
> or Turkish. No idea it was Itai.

This is from *Triangle at Rhodes* Agatha Christie (1936 story, 1989 TV adaptation). The character didn't know Rhodes was 'Itai'.

Comment: What is the source of this sentence please? When asking about sentences that others have written (or said), please provide a source and author, and if possible a link so that additional context is available. If a link is not possible, please provide additional context. -- at a guess (which is all that is possible without more context) this is short for "Italian". I am not giving this as an answer because more context is needed.

Comment: @Michael Harvey
 Thanks. I know that story, in fact I own a copy, although I have not seen that dramatization of it. "Eyti" was once slang for "Italian" not very polite slang, although nicer than "Wop".  It was current in the first half of the 20th century in the US, and I think in the UK also, but I am not sure. That **might** be the answer.

Comment: Bravo, gentlemen. The investigation worthy of Poirot himself. @MichaelHarvey if you please make that an answer, I will accept.

Comment: I meant @DavidSiegel, of course. Apologies.

Comment: @user3156459 - generally, people are reluctant to answer an off-topic question like this one. Answers to off-topic questions can be downvoted.

Comment: I see. Why this question would be  an “off-topic” in this section of stackexchange?

Comment: No details of where the quote came from, and none of any research you have done.

Comment: From https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic :The best questions are those that have specific answers; ELL is not a general discussion forum. In general, ask here if you have a question which covers:

Word choice, usage, and meaning

Comment: "Questions that can be answered by a quick dictionary lookup " are technically off-topic, but this one can't without the guess on the recorded spelling first. . @MichaelHarvey I've done fairly well in avoiding too many downvotes, and generally I dislike it when questions are answered by only a comment, If I think I can justify an answer, I will often post one.

Comment: Indeed, I hit a wall after a dictionary search, and googling gave me “ Meaning:the Lord is with me. Itai as a boy's name is of Hebrew origin” which didn’t help much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Eyetie) gives

> "Eyetie", less commonly "Eytie" *adjective or noun*

(Pronounced  Eye·​tie,  \ ˈītē , ˈīˌtī )
as meaning "italian" *often disparaging + offensive*

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Eyetie) gives a similar meaning. So does [The urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=eytie)

These would all be pronounced in much the same way as "Itai" All of these date the term to the WWII era, and I was about to put this down to an anachronism introduced by the script writers, but [this OED page](https://public.oed.com/appeals/eyetie/) reads:

> One notable feature of the vocabulary of the First World War is the number of (often offensive) terms coined for soldiers of different nationalities. One of these is Eyetie (spelled in various ways, including Iti and Eyety) meaning ‘Italian’. Eyetalian was already in use in the 19th century, but the abbreviated form Eyetie appears to have been a WWI coinage. The earliest evidence we have found so far is:
>
> > Our army in Italy always spoke of the Italians as the ‘Itis’ (pronounced ‘Eye-ties’). *1919 Athenæum 22 Aug., p. 791/2*
>
> This indicates that the term was used during the war; is there any earlier written evidence?

Thus it seems that the term was already in use when the underlying story was written in 1936, although the term does not seem to appear in the written story.

Comment: What is the underlying story?  There's noting in the question about WWI

Comment: @JamesK - Not provided by OP - 'Triangle at Rhodes' Agatha Christie (1936 story, 1989 TV adaptation). Character didn't know Rhodes was 'Eyetie' (Italian). Was from 1912 to 1947 then Greek. I must say that I have had a lifelong interest in low speech and its representation in literature, and I have never before seen 'Itai' instead of 'Eyetie'. I wonder if it was done out of an odd kind of delicacy. It is present in the script spelled thus, and is an invention of the 1989 TV adapters (no such remark appears in the 1936 story).

Comment: @JamesK Michael Harvey  identified the story in a comment to which I responded, and whch was later, I think, deleted. This was all before I posted my answer.

Comment: Worth noting, perhaps, that a TV, play, or film script is a set of instructions to actors, specifying what they are to say. The script was not intended to be published as literature.

Comment: I wrote "I have never before seen 'Itai' instead of 'Eyetie'. I wonder if it was done out of an odd kind of delicacy" - the explanation could equally well be ignorance.